# Public setter method will not update

Tags: c#

So I've been scratching my head on this one for a while and I cannot figure it out.  I went through some debugging steps to see where it's hanging up, and Visual Studio will not give me anything.  Basically, I have a class with an array that keeps track of the current index to the array and the current image.

However, when I'm debugging (or not debugging), no matter what the value of "index" is, "currentLocation" doesn't get updated.  I can't seem to figure out what the problem might be.  Any suggestions?

```
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //...

    public void GoTo(int index)
    {
        if (index == currentLocation)
            return;
        else if (index >= data.Length)
            this.currentLocation = data.Length - 1;
        else if (index <= 0)
            this.currentLocation = 0;
        else
            this.currentLocation = index;

        //this is where the debugging drops off
    }

    //doesn't matter if I initialize the value or not
    //private int _currentLocation = 0;
    private int _currentLocation;
    public int currentLocation
    {
        get { return _currentLocation; }
        set 
        { 
            //never hits this line
            this.SetProperty(ref this._currentLocation, value); 
            //more work 
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: You don't need the first `if`.  Drop it, and see what happens.

Comment: I actually use that if statement to make sure that I don't 'update' the value if the new index is the same as the currentLocation.  However, I tried removing the if statement (and return statement) anyways and it still didn't change anything.

Comment: @EthanShafer usually you should use such check in property setter

Comment: could you please clarify "never hits this line"? do you have breakpoint  in the setter?

Comment: I have the breakpoint within the GoTo function, when I step through, debugging never gets to the setter.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, fair point, I'll try reworking it so the check is within the currentLocation setter and see if that changes anything.

Comment: It is a standard debugger behavior. Try to set breakpoint in the setter

Comment: @EthanShafer maybe you always hit condition `index == currentLocation`?

Comment: Put breakpoint inside setter, debugger skip props get and set.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that the debugger doesn't hit property getters and setters.  Turns out the error is somewhere else in the application.  Appreciate that help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your answers in comments we see that you do not have any breakpoint in the setter, but trying to get there using F11 (step into). It will not work until you disable corresponding debugger settings. Open Tools->Options->Debugging. Find option "Step over properties and operators" (should be enabled by default) and disable it. Or set breakpoint in the setter, if it is more convenient.